# Java: Removing brackets and commas from a Stringbuffer displaying an ArrayList

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, stringbuffer

Let's say currently I have an ArrayList which I want to display in my java program.

I have a Stringbuffer like this one:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
    text.append("First name: ");
    text.append(firstname);
    text.append("   ");
    text.append("Last name: ");
    text.append(lastname);

    //to give each result it's own line
    text.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    return text.toString();
}
```

The method is called here:

```
NameDaoImpl name1 = new NameDaoImpl();
        Collection<NameBean> names = name1.getNames();
        System.out.println(betriebe);
```

The getNames() method is a PreparedStatement which runs through all the found results and returns them.

It gives me this result:

```
[First name: firstname1   Last name: lastname1
, First name: firstname2   Last name: lastname2
, First name: firstname3   Last name: lastname3
]
```

But I want it to appear without the brackets and commas. How do I exactly do that? I tried it with the methods replace and replaceall, but then they always give me an error like this:

```
return text.toString().replaceAll("[","").replaceAll("]","").replaceAll(",", "");
```

I always get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0
>   [

Am I using the wrong methods? Should I use a different one or is the mistake somewhere else?

Comment: the brackets are not created by the method you've posted. Please post where you call this method!

Comment: `replaceAll` takes a regex as parameter and `[` as a special meaning.

Comment: That's a line of code crying out to be chopped into 3 individual lines for debugging.

Comment: replaceAll is expecting a valid regular expression. Brackets are part of the reg expression alphabeth. Escape them with backslash "\["

Comment: You need to use `return text.toString().replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]","").replaceAll(",", "");` to avoid issues with `replaceAll`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added the implementation of the method.

Comment: I've also tried to escape the brackets with two backslashes already, but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Your `toString()` function is perfectly fine as it is. It does not contain brackets anyway ;-)

The brackets are emitted by the `ArrayList`'s `toString()` method. You could replace that by a `StringBuilder` and a loop through your list.

BTW you could use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. No need for synchronization here.

Comment: Hmm I never worked with a stringbuilder before. I'll have a look at it. How would I remove those brackets and commas in a loop though?

Comment: @cadrian Doesn't necessarily make a difference, post Java 6 (although I would use StringBuilder myself): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Escape_analysis_and_lock_coarsening

Comment: @APL using `StringBuilder` doesn't affect the brackets and commas, it is literally just in your implementation of `toString()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, I was not aware of that optimization.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print them without the brackets and commas, don't call `toString()` on your collection directly: that is what is inserting them:

```
for (NameBean name : name1.getNames()) {
  System.out.print(name);
}
```

Or, if you want it in a String:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (NameBean name : name1.getNames()) {
  sb.append(name);
}
String str = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before, but with both of these methods it returns something like this instead of the data contained iny the array: "business.persons.NameBean@512eacf1"

Comment: That is because you haven't overridden toString on NameBean correctly - you must have had the same if you called toString on the collection too, since that calls toString on the elements.